# Using custom tiles in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am pretty new to the Google Maps API v2 and would like to integrate a map available via this base link: [https://tiles.guildwars2.com/{continent_id}/{floor}/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.jpg](https://tiles.guildwars2.com/%7Bcontinent_id%7D/%7Bfloor%7D/%7Bzoom%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.jpg). My problem is, well everything, but let's get started with the following:

1) How can I set the map sizes that there is no grey space at any side?
[image]
2) How can I move the map correctly because I have obviously 4 parameters while I can change only 3 at a time with getTileUrl?
3) Why are the tiles mixed and not shown in their correct order?

The map documentation is available here:
http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:2/maps
http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:Maps

Working example link: [0.jpg](https://tiles.guildwars2.com/1/0/1/1/0.jpg)

My current code is:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class mapsContainer extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private TileOverlay mSelectedTileOverlay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_container);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

            /**
             * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state.
             */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /**
             * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state.
             */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        View navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            TextView connectionStatus = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.connection_status);
            connectionStatus.setText(R.string.common_online);
        } else {
            TextView connectionStatus = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.connection_status);
            connectionStatus.setText(R.string.common_offline);
        }

        toggle.syncState();

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapsFragement, mapFragment).commit();

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        toggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.syncProfile) {
            //String res = gwApiAccess.apiQueryAuthorized("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/account/dyes");
            //Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"res: " + res);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, profile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_itemDB) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, items.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_guilds) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, guilds.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_maps) {
            //Do nothing
        } else if (id == R.id.settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
        CustomUrlTileProvider mTileProvider = new CustomUrlTileProvider(256, 256, "https://tiles.guildwars2.com/{continent_id}/{floor}/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.jpg");
        mSelectedTileOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mTileProvider).zIndex(-1));
        mMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
    }

    private static class CustomUrlTileProvider extends UrlTileProvider {

        private String baseUrl;

        CustomUrlTileProvider(int width, int height, String url) {
            super(width, height);
            this.baseUrl = url;
        }

        @Override
        public URL getTileUrl(int zoom, int x, int y) {
            try {
                return new URL(baseUrl.replace("{continent_id}", "" + 1).replace("{floor}", "" + 0).replace("{zoom}", "" + zoom).replace("{x}", "" + x).replace("{y}", "" + y));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private boolean checkTileExists(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            int minZoom = 0;
            int maxZoom = 0;

            return !(zoom < minZoom || zoom > maxZoom);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show a working example of a correct URL? Could you elaborate more on "How can I set the map sizes that there is no grey space at any side?"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after having a looooong break because of school I figured everything out except the first thing.

My fault with the wrong tiles was that I did not have the correct order of params.

The other thing with the to much params, I will program myself a workaround in the near future.

So I will close the thread and open a new one just before I smash the display because sth doesn't work.